Why does np.array() use square brackets [ ], while np.zeros() uses parentheses ( )?
I'm learning NumPy and noticed a difference in how inputs are provided to some of its functions:
When using np.array(), I pass the data inside square brackets [], like this:
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])

But when using np.zeros(), I pass the shape inside parentheses (), like this:
zeros_array = np.zeros((2, 3))

Why does np.array() require square brackets, while np.zeros() requires parentheses? Is there a specific reason behind this difference in syntax?

Study some more basic python.  [] make lists, (,) make tuples. Often either one can be used, though not always.

The only "requirement" for that syntax is a sequence.  Both syntaxes work, although arrays tend to be lists and shapes tend to be tuples.  See below for the opposite example of your post:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array((1, 2, 3))
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.zeros([2, 3])
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])

The documentation for numpy.array specifically says ...any (nested) sequence.  numpy.zeros says int or tuple of ints but as implemented any sequence works.
